# Where is time travel introduced in Anima?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

I just read a question about time travel in anima and I'm wondering there.
I've the core rules book from the beginning of the anima-rpg and at least in there I don't remember reading anything about that. So my question is: Is there any book where time travel in anima has been introduced and if so which one?

Answer (score 3):

Time travel as per the classic definition (physically moving oneself to a different time) is not mentioned, at least not to the past. If you analize the several means that exists for traveling time or altering past events, you'll realize a trend: They are severely limited in one or more ways.

- In the core book, we have the Eye of time spell, that allows you to
  send your senses to the past and observe the events that transpired.
  Note that this is he wording from the second edition of the core rules , first edition description
  is much more ambiguous, categorizing it as a "limited time travel"
  that allows you to witness past events, but it was not clear about
  the limit of you interactions with those events.
- The spell Uncreate allow to erase things from existence, but it is
  limited in that it so it can only be used on things that exists in
  the present, and past events involving the uncreated objects or being
  are not affected, they merely happened in another way that did not
  required the uncreated entities.
- In Arcana exxet you can find the time path of magic, that allow
  manipulation of time, but most of the spells only works on limited
  areas or specific targets. It can slow or stop time, or make things
  or people older or younger, etc. Among the higher level spells you
  can find effective time travelling (but only to the future), time
  rewind(but only in a a small zone and only small amounts of
  time),time loops (but only in a limited area) and even the ability to
  overlap past and present, but the spell is unable to effectively
  alter the past.

The important part, however, is at the end of the time path spell list: A small note informs that the Powers in Shadow continually surveys te use of magic that mess with time, and that any spell that could end in an alteration of the past is left without effect. Is possible that they are trying to prevent any disaster, or maybe there is something in the past that they want to remain forgotten, but the case is that there is no aparent means for time traveling because there is certain parties very interested in making that impossible.

Of course, that the temporal blockade is really impassable or not is in the hands of the DM, and would not be the first time that the Imperium systems fails them...