# Is there any limit to what you can Move beyond weight and the range of your Magic Projection?

Tags: spells, targeting, anima-beyond-fantasy

My GM and I are on opposite sides of a debate about the applicability of a spell from the Path of Air I have reproduced below:

> Move
>
> Effect: This spell allows the spellcaster to move inanimate objects without physical contact over a distance with a maximum speed equivalent to Flight Value 10.  The maximum weight he can effect is 60 pounds.

I would argue that this spell simply grants the caster the ability to move objects within their range, while the GM has currently ruled that it needs to target an object.  As this particular spell has Daily maintenance, that distinction has a lot of bearing on its applicability to many situations.  Are either of us right?

Comment: Just a note. The spell has daily mainteneance in the first edition of anima, but that's no longer the case in the revised edition.

Comment: @MACN: Good to know!  Now to never tell my GM.  ;P  (but seriously what differentiates it from the Free Access spell that does that on a per-turn maintenance, in that case?)

Comment: In the revised edition ( aka Core exxet, not to confuse with [the english revised edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51117/9078) ) both spells are for the most part identical. A bunch of free access spells are identical or sligthy watered down versions of utility spells of a sphere so that you can have that utility spell whitout having to invest points in that sphere. Also, The Core exxet edition is not very known outside Spain because it was never translated to english, so many groups ignore it completely.

Comment: @MACN yeah.  We're mostly ignoring it in my group.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find anything very specific in the book, but if you read spell level 86 from the same path of magic, you can see the differences between gaining telekinesis and just moving an object. I will believe that it is a targeted spell that will require you to cast it for each object that you want to move.

Comment: The difference between Move and the level 86 spell is *mass*, not *method.*  At least, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Distance limits apply for everything where it is not stated. In this case it is covered by projection. There is a table located on page 110 of the Core Book for this.

In any case, the weight limit would be the combined weight of everything that is being attempted to be lifted. This spell is definitely a minor form of telekinesis. In the Magic Errata from the Core Exxet it was re-written as a per round maintenance.

The takeaway here; The weight is low enough that its not really an issue for the spell to be fairly flexible, and I think that is the intent.

Comment: When you say "the combined weight of everything that is being attempted to be lifted", do you mean "specifically the objects the spell is being used on" or "the objects the spell is being used on plus everything those objects are supporting and so on"?

Comment: Ill give an example: If I weigh 80 kilograms, but I'm wearing a suit of plate armor, and carrying a sword, a shield, and a backpack full of rations, rope and other stuff like it, my effective weight is much higher than 80 kilo's. Basically, this spell amounts to similar usefulness to mage hand in D&D, except it's actually worse anyhow. The way the spell reads implies it can lift multiple objects up to the weight limit.